# Can't close ActionOverflow directly

Tags: python-2.7, kivy

I have 2 `Screens` in my app (ScreenManager). One of them has `ActionBar` with `ActionOverflow`. I have button that should change current `Screen` and close `ActionOverflow`, but the `Screen` changes and `ActionOverflow` remains open until
I tap the screen in another place.

Here some code:

```
# .kv
ScreenManager:
    id: ScrMan
    Screen:
        name: 'scr1'
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            ActionBar:
                ActionView:
                    ActionOverflow:
                        id: ActOv
                        #some buttons
                        ActionButton:
                            text: 'some text'
                            on_press: 
                                ActOv.is_open = False
                                #I also tried: is_open = False; self.parent.is_open = False; with the same result
                                ScrMan.current = 'scr2'

    Screen:
        name: 'scr2'
        #some cool stuff here
```

How I can change the screen and close ActionOverflow list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: As you have version 1.9.1 (or older master branch, there was [this](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/commit/275cb51b2015685998cf87c2877239c270b20af2#diff-4b5fa03b170bae63a329314d2bab8866R263) fix missing. Changing `actionbar.py` in `<python dir>/Lib/site-packages/kivy/uix/actionbar.py` brings the default behavior to the old version.

---

The dropdown should close on its own by default. Maybe there's something wrong in your code e.g. placing `ActionButton` into `ActionOverflow` as a widget or maybe something else. Try this:

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.base import runTouchApp
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
Builder.load_string('''
#:import Clock kivy.clock.Clock
#:import partial functools.partial
<Test>:
    ScreenManager:
        id: ScrMan
        Screen:
            name: 'scr1'
            ActionBar:
                pos_hint: {'top': 1}
                ActionView:
                    ActionPrevious:
                    ActionOverflow:
                    ActionButton:
                        text: 'some very very long text'
                    ActionButton:
                        text: 'some very very long text'
                    ActionButton:
                        text: 'some very very long text'
                    ActionButton:
                        text: 'some very very long text'
                    ActionButton:
                        text: 'some very very long text'
                    ActionButton:
                        text: 'try this button!'
                        on_press: 
                            ScrMan.current = 'scr2'
                            Clock.schedule_once(partial(root.change_scr, ScrMan), 1)
        Screen:
            name: 'scr2'
            Label:
                text: 'second'
''')
class Test(BoxLayout):
    def change_scr(self, man, *dt):
        man.current = man.previous()
runTouchApp(Test())
```

Comment: Unfortunantely, your solution didn't helpend. 
First: your `very very long strings` did not fit into buttons, 
I fixed this adding `minimum_width: '200sp'`
Second: when I press the button, screen changes to the second one and returns back. `ActionOverflow` remains open during this

Comment: You have version 1.9.1 (or older master branch. Put [this](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/commit/275cb51b2015685998cf87c2877239c270b20af2#diff-4b5fa03b170bae63a329314d2bab8866R263) fix in your `actionbar.py` in `<python dir>/Lib/site-packages/kivy/uix/actionbar.py`

Comment: Yes, I have 1.9.1 on PC and 1.9.0 on tablet (qpy) this fix helpend me on PC

Comment: @EugeneErshov It won't work with Qpython, they don't update the app as often as it would be necessary to maintain Kivy too. The latest stable version is 1.9.1, which means they use quite an old version, because the current(master) version is 1.9.2. It'd be better to either use Kivy Launcher directly from google play, or build a custom one with the latest stable or master versions.

Comment: I have one more question. I'm writing code on PC (win) and Android tablet (qpy + kivy Launcher for testing) while I'm not at home. Also I have Ubuntu VM with Ubuntu on PC with buildozer for creating apk. Your fix helped me and I can run my code correctly on Windows, Ubuntu and even qpy and kivy Launcher, but when I'm creating apk it does not have fix. `ActionOverdlow` remains open. I tried deleting both .buildozer folders but it didn't help (I applied fix to kivy on Ubuntu and it works)

Comment: @EugeneErshov buildozer is a little bit different, it has its own version of kivy. I'm not sure what version of Kivy it uses by default, but try to put `kivy==master` to requirements, it should fetch the correct version. Or... look for the file on your disk in a folder related to buildozer, either that `.buildozer` or somewhere in `.local` to edit it with such a fix.

Comment: I found kivy folder there. Everything works perfect now

Comment: @EugeneErshov I edited the answer with a solution thag worked for you.

Comment: Now i have opposite problem :o I used `ActionToggleButton` and dont want `ActionOverflow` to close when this button is pressed. How to prevent this?

Comment: @EugeneErshov `<ActionDropdown>: auto_dismiss: False` should do the thing.

Comment: @EugeneErshov with [this](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/pull/4718) fix it'll work. It seems I forgot to check if it worked even with kv, but I'm sure I tested it somewhere within python.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127654/discussion-between-eugene-ershov-and-keyweeusr).